# Mixing exercises with multiple muscle groups

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, muscle-groups

My current workout routine is as follows.

```
Monday : Chest and Biceps
Tuesday : Shoulder and Triceps
Wednesday : Back and Legs.
Repeat Mon and Tues for Thursday and Friday
Saturday : Cricket (morning to evening)
Sunday : Rest.
```

While doing Chest and Biceps, is it Ok to do 1 Chest exercise followed by 1 Biceps again Chest and so on (which I am following now) or is it necessary to complete the Chest cycle first and then go for the Biceps? Same for all other day exercises.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The routine of mixing different muscle groups one after another so that one can recover while you're working the other is called a "super set" routine. But Eric's right, unless you've got a 1200 total (squat+dl+bp maxes), if you're interested in raw strength, then SS is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the order of exercises you're currently performing.  However, to avoid a training plateau, you should consider changing up your routine on a regular basis.  Typically, that's every 6 to 8 weeks.  For example, as you've asked, perform all chest exercises first, then biceps.  Or, perform biceps first, then chest.  You should base it on what you think you need improvement on so that you can perform those exercises early on in your routine.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch your routine and go with the Starting Strength program. It will be much more effective in the short and long term.

1. Buy [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982522738).
2. Follow [the program](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs).
3. Become strong and powerful.

You're wasting time doing isolation exercises, missing out on hormone bumps that come from compound lifts, getting yourself out of muscular balance, not on any kind of predictable load increase, and lining yourself up for injuries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Eric. Its been a while I started following that routine and I am happy with it. I don’t want to change it for some more time at least. I just want to know whether its ok to mix exercises or not.